# Incremental training using TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I want to train a model to classify 90K labels, so I used the so called incremental training.

I initially train the model to classify only 1K labels, then add another 1K labels and expand the final FC layer's output dimension to 2K, and train for some more epochs. After that I add another 1K labels, and so on...

Note that it is NOT fine-tune, in which ALL parameters before the last FC are fixed, so I can cache the output features. In my case I need to update all variables in every stage.

The solution I designed is:

1. train for 1K labels.
2. save the model.
3. modify the graph to let the last FC layer output 2K dimension.
4. initialize all variables
5. load the previous checkpoint, which will override all parameters, but the last layer's weights.
6. train again and repeat

So the key point here is to realize partial restore checkpoints.

In TensorFlow, I use such code to load a checkpoint:

```
saver.restore(sess, "model.ckpt")
```

However, it fails when there is shape mismatch.

Could anyone help, either in how to partially restore/initialize variables, or how to implement incremental training in another way?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not simple to do. We are actively adding new APIs to make it easier.

In the meantime, if you are really determined, :), you can try the following when you change the FC layer's size:

- Create a reader:
  reader = tf.train.NewCheckpointReader(your_checkpoint_file)
- Load all the variables in the checkpoint file:
  cur_vars = reader.get_variable_to_shape_map().keys()
- Remove the original FC layer:
  cur_vars_without_fc = cur_vars - your_fc_layer_var_name
- Create a saver with these variables:
  saver = tf.Saver(cur_vars_without_fc)
  saver.restore(sess, your_checkpoint_file)
- Initialize your new FC layer's variables:
  sess.run([your_fc_layer_var.initializer])

Hope that helps!

Sherry